# JQuery, values wont update after clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Got my little calculator working in jquery, but i got a small problem. When i check the checkbox it multiples the input of field 1 and 2 with 10. But if i input the values in field 1 and 2 BEFORE checking the checkbox it wont update with the new value.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/02bq3h8t/

Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
                $('#a2').keyup(calculate);
                $('#a3').keyup(calculate);
            });
            function calculate(e) {

            if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
                $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())*0.6);
                $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());          
            } else {
                $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());
                $('#a4').val($('#a3').val() * 0.5);
            }}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div>Lengde <input id="a1" type="text" value="0" /></div>
    <div>Bredde <input id="a2" type="text" value="0" /></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_check"></div>
    <div>Antall kvm <input id="a3" type="text" value="0" /></div>
    <div>Pris <input id="a4" type="text" value="0" /></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another event for the checkbox, so the values will update if the checked state changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
    $('#a2').keyup(calculate);
    $('#a3').keyup(calculate);
    $(".checkbox_check").change(calculate);
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an event handler for the state change of your checkboxes. Your values are only recalculated if you actually trigger it. Just add inside your `$(document).ready()`function:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(calculate);
```

Comment: Jepp that does it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just had a small logical mistake.

You simply did not call your `calculate` function when the checkbox changes. See the working fiddle with an `EventListener` attached to the `checkbox` to call the function:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
      $('#a2').keyup(calculate);
      $('#a3').keyup(calculate);
        /*---- This line was missing ----*/
        $('.checkbox_check').change(calculate);
  });
  function calculate(e) {

  if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
   $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())*10);
   $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());   
  } else {
   $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());
      $('#a4').val($('#a3').val() * 0.5);
  }}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>Lengde <input id="a1" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div>Bredde <input id="a2" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_check"></div>
<div>Antall kvm <input id="a3" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div>Pris <input id="a4" type="text" value="0" /></div>
</body>
```